Replace ordinal numbers in R?
In R, suppose I have a string vector composed of words:
string1<-c("1ST COMPANY", "21ST LIBRARY")

However, within these strings, I want to convert ordinal number words like "1ST" into "First" and "21ST" into "Twenty-first". Is there any way to convert these ordinal number strings into just words like "First"? My ideal output would be:
string2<-c("FIRST COMPANY", "TWENTY-FIRST LIBRARY")


textclean::replace_ordinal can get you pretty close. stringr::str_to_upper(textclean::replace_ordinal(stringr::str_to_lower(string1)))

Extract words like "1ST", "21ST" then extract their numerical values. The function english::ordinal() will convert these numerical values into their representation like first, twenty-first.
library(stringr)
library(english)
library(readr)

str_replace_all(string1, "\\b\\d+(ST|ND|RD|TH)\\b", ~ ordinal(parse_number(.))) |>
  str_to_upper()
# [1] "FIRST COMPANY"        "TWENTY-FIRST LIBRARY"


Here is a not-so-pretty hack:
# create ordinals look up
ordinals <- c("1"="FIRST","21"="TWENTY-FIRST")

# split string1
split_string1 <- c(unlist(strsplit(string1,split = " ")))

# convert ordinals in split_string1 into numbers
my_nums <- c()
for(i in split_string1){
  my_nums <- c(my_nums,sub("(\\d+)(ST|ND|RD|TH)","\\1",i))
}

# using the index positions of the target ordinals, 
# replace them with their word equivalent from look up
split_string1[c(1,3)] <- ordinals[my_nums[c(1,3)]]

# concatenate
split_string1 <- paste(split_string1,collapse = " ")

print(split_string1)

"FIRST COMPANY TWENTY-FIRST LIBRARY"

Hope it helps!
